# Solutions to $f(x) + x\,f'(x)= f(2x)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, functional-equations

I was trying to solve a question in physics that involved a spring that had uniformly distributed mass. To find out how the speed of a small segment of the spring varied from the distance x from the base of the spring I used the fact that the integral of m*v over all the parts of the spring will be equal to mass * velocity of the center of mass. I ended up with this differential equation. However, I have no clue how to solve it.

So, what I need is solutions to $f(x) + x\,f'(x) = f(2x)$.

Based on intuition, I guessed a linear polynomial and it fits the equation but I was wondering if there exist more functions that fit the given equation.

Comment: Mathematicians don't use $*$ for multiplication, because if they did, they would be consistent about it ($2x$ would be $2*x$ etc)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unaware. What symbol should I use instead?

Comment: Nothing at all. I already edited it. Don't worry about it.

Comment: You can use \cdot looks like this $m\cdot v$, though in general you can write it without $\cdot$ unless there are numbers like $15\cdot 12$ you shouldn't write $1512$ :)

Comment: Your physics might be wrong, how are the values at position $x$ and $2x$ connected in a physically plausible way? Also note that by Taylor $f(2x)=f(x+x)=f(x)+f'(x)x+\frac12f''(x+\theta x)x^2$.

Comment: Hey, the physics probably isn't wrong at a highschool level. So what I did was that the integral of f(x)*dm from 0 to 2x divided by mass will be equal to the velocity at x (f(x)). This is because the spring's mass is uniformly distributed. Now differentiate both sides and rearrange a little and you get that differential equation. I don't know how to use Latex. If you want I can attach a pic showing my calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
Then 
$$f(x)+x\,f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n+a_1x+2a_2x^2+3a_3x^3+\cdots$$
and 
$$f(2x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^na_nx^n$$
so we get
$$a_n+na_n=2^na_n$$
which implies $a_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$.

Conclusion: among all real-analytic functions (a fancy name for real valued functions that have a representation as a power series), only linear functions satisfy the equation.

Now, since the problem comes from physics, it is actually solved.

Comment: The last line got a good laugh out of me. $+1$

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me an example of a function that isn't representable in a power series?

Comment: Yes. The function that is equal to $e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x\neq 0$ and zero at $x=0$. All the derivatives of this function vanish at $x=0$, so it does not have a power series representation around zero.